# Reading XML with JSONP

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have seen a few answers to similar problems on here already, and have given them all a good read! The issue I am facing, is that I cannot get the TfL cycle hire feed to work with JSONP, and this just returns a 404, whereas if you put the link in a browser, it is there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // CYCLE HIRE DATA

    var cycleHireUrl = 'http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: cycleHireUrl,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data["station"], function(index, item) {
                var name = item.name;
                $('.cycles').append('<div>' + name + '</div>')
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I seem to get a string of extra stuff appended to my URL in the console, which may be causing the error:

```
GET http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml?callback=jQuery110209581123229581863_1381759036915&_=1381759036916 404 (Not Found)
```

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Your service does not support JSONP.

Comment: jQuery appends those parameters to the url in order to facilitate the JSONP callback function.

In your case however, the service returns XML, which is not JSONP. Does the service you are using support JSONP?

Comment: hint: you won't be able to get that xml via js due to cross domain policies (which is why I presume you're trying jsonp)... instead use a server-side script as a proxy (if you will...) to load the xml, and in your js, hit your server-side script. ta-da!

Answer (score 0):

JSONP stands for JavaScript Object Notation with Padding. This means a standard JSON string that is wrapped in a function call. The function is executed but if there is a JavaScript function with that name on your page (or added in dynamically by jQuery). If there is no function in your HTML with that same name the call will fail and if the string inside that JSONP block isn't JSON it will fail. This this case the 404 is telling you that the service is not willing to return anything regardless of format.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the TFL feeds are generally meant to be used from your own server, rather than from client-side Javascript. The fact you have to register particular IP addresses for use with them is a bit of a hint. The cycle feed certainly looks as if it's XML only, not JSON or JSONP, presumably for this reason.

I think your only option if you want to deliver the cycle availability results as JSONP is to set up a server that queries TFL, reads the XML response, converts what you need to JSONP and returns it to your client.